# Terraform AWS Cloudwatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

Here is an example of a `cloudwatch_metric_alarm resource`:

```
    resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb_healthyhosts" {
  alarm_name          = "alarmname"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.logstash_servers_count
  alarm_description   = "Number of healthy nodes in Target Group"
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.sns.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.sns.arn]
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = aws_lb_target_group.lb-tg.arn_suffix
    LoadBalancer = aws_lb.lb.arn_suffix
  }
}
```

I still don't understand the Alarm Actions Argument. In the terraform documentation, we have:

> alarm_actions - (Optional) The list of actions to execute when this alarm transitions into an ALARM state from any other state. Each
> action is specified as an Amazon Resource Name (ARN).

Could someone give me a concrete example for that, for example sending an Email / and / Creating an SNS Topic ( without an exiting topic ARN ).

I thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: The `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` resource doesn't handle the actual message delivery whether it's via email, SMS or whatever. The only thing that it does is pass the message to an SNS topic which is defined in `alarm_actions`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for an example, it would looks like as follow.

First you need to create your alarm and in the in the alarm actions field reference to your sns topic arn:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb_healthyhosts" {
  alarm_name          = "alarmname"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.logstash_servers_count
  alarm_description   = "Number of healthy nodes in Target Group"
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.alarm.arn]
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = aws_lb_target_group.lb-tg.arn_suffix
    LoadBalancer = aws_lb.lb.arn_suffix
  }
}
```

Then create the SNS topic and subscribe your email to that topic:

```
# SNS topic to send emails with the Alerts
resource "aws_sns_topic" "alarm" {
  name              = "my-alarm-topic"
  kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.sns_encryption_key.id
  delivery_policy   = <<EOF
{
  "http": {
    "defaultHealthyRetryPolicy": {
      "minDelayTarget": 20,
      "maxDelayTarget": 20,
      "numRetries": 3,
      "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
      "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
      "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
      "backoffFunction": "linear"
    },
    "disableSubscriptionOverrides": false,
    "defaultThrottlePolicy": {
      "maxReceivesPerSecond": 1
    }
  }
}
EOF
  ## This local exec, suscribes your email to the topic 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws sns subscribe --topic-arn ${self.arn} --protocol email --notification-endpoint ${var.your_email} --region ${var.main_region}"
  }
}


## KMS Key to encrypt the SNS topic (security best practises)
resource "aws_kms_key" "sns_encryption_key" {
  description             = "alarms sns topic encryption key"
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
  enable_key_rotation     = true
}
```

Comment: Hello. I come back for a question. Under dimensions, I see in the AWS Documentation that only a few dimensions for EC2 Instances available are ( like instance ID - etc .... ) . In my project, I am using a Tag called " Type " to categorize my instances to HTTP or APP instances.
Is there any mean to create alarms based on those tags as dimensions ? Meaning creating alarms for instances with the TAG " Http " and alarms for instances Tagged as " App " .
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I've never done it before, but afik this can be done with [custom metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html#usingDimensions) I'm sorry I cannot give you a specific example. If this solution does not fit your requirement, post a new question, I'm sure someone in the SO community will be able to help you. Thanks,